# Validate unique attributes JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is there a way to define some attributes from my schema to create a combination and validate if a json document already exist using JSON Schema?

For example consider the below pokemon schema:

```
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/2020-12/schema,
 "title": "pokemon",
 "description" : "a simple pokemon test",
 "type": "object",
 "properties" : {
 "name":{
 "type":"string"
  },
 "owner":{
 "type":"string"
 },
 "color":{
  "type":"string"
  }

  }
```

What I want is to define color and owner as my unique key and then every time there is a POST call identify if there exist already a pokemon with those values, if so then reject and not save the data. Not sure if I can do this by extending the schema and add an extra property to every property like a boolean and then compare.

Comment: Rejecting a specific combination of values based on historical data sounds like application logic, and not something for JSON Schema to do.

Comment: yes, and what attributes I want to use for validation can be stored inside of my JSON Schema?... I can think only in that option, I was trying to see if there is something better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I get into the schema support options, I'd like to address your usage.

JSON Schema is able to validate a single JSON document (the *instance*).  Because of this, it can check the data it contains against a schema, but not against external data.

It looks like what you're wanting to do is check an incoming instance against a database.  This isn't supported by JSON Schema.  JSON Schema can only validate the incoming instance in this case.

Your best bet is to just query the DB for a matching value using the query language of the DB itself.  Most DBs will also allow you to define uniqueness constraints.  Some allow for multiple values, but if yours only supports a single value for uniqueness constraints, you can always store a composite value like `{color}_{owner}` and define a constraint on that.

If you still want to use JSON Schema to provide this validation, then I think you'll need to describe a bit more of your architecture.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree that the logic to insert or reject the data should be either in a query using db as you said or programatically in the code. 
What I was looking for is the best approach to store the attributes within the JSON Schema for my unique key. At the end the final user can decide which attributes they want to use and then I can take those and do the validation against the existing data.

Comment: That's fine, but JSON Schema isn't going to help validate against existing data that's external to the instance you give it.